# Start Activity from ListView item click in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view with image. When I press (on click) list view , need to open individual activity. But when I press the text view , it gives error message(crashes app). Here is my code. Could you please help me in this regard ?

SMSMainPage.java:

```
public class SmsMainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    //log tag
    private static final String TAG = "SaidursApp";

    // Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "SmsMainPage  onCreate function started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_main_page);

        //Code for showing image and list view item
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, mobileArray));


        Log.v(TAG, "SmsMainPage  setOnItemClickListener started");
        try {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) view;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(SmsMainPage.this, android.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity0);
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Nothing do!
                    }
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

MobileArrayAdapterCode.java:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    //log tag
    private static final String TAG = "SaidursApp";

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_listview, values);
        Log.v(TAG, "MobileArrayAdapter  function started");
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowsmobile_logo);
        } else if (s.equals("IPhone")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
        } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

## Full Log Cat :

```
08-30 14:17:53.269    4613-4613/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-30 14:17:53.295    4613-4623/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
08-30 14:17:53.416    4613-4634/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
08-30 14:17:53.423    4613-4613/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
08-30 14:17:53.469    4613-4634/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
08-30 14:17:53.480    4613-4634/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
08-30 14:17:53.512    4613-4634/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
08-30 14:17:53.547    4613-4634/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-30 14:17:53.553    4613-4634/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-30 14:17:54.450    4613-4633/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ SmsMainPage class started
08-30 14:17:54.454    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ SmsMainPage  onCreate function started
08-30 14:17:54.472    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ SmsMainPageFragment function started
08-30 14:17:54.472    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ SmsMainPageFragment onCreateView function started
08-30 14:17:54.476    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter  function started
08-30 14:17:54.477    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ SmsMainPage  setOnItemClickListener started
08-30 14:17:54.503    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.506    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.506    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Android
08-30 14:17:54.509    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.510    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.510    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ IPhone
08-30 14:17:54.513    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.515    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.515    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ WindowsMobile
08-30 14:17:54.516    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.518    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.518    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Blackberry
08-30 14:17:54.548    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.550    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.550    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Android
08-30 14:17:54.551    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.552    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.553    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ IPhone
08-30 14:17:54.553    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.555    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.555    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ WindowsMobile
08-30 14:17:54.556    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.557    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.557    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Blackberry
08-30 14:17:54.558    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.559    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.559    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Android
08-30 14:17:54.560    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.561    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.561    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ IPhone
08-30 14:17:54.562    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.563    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.564    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ WindowsMobile
08-30 14:17:54.565    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.566    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.566    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Blackberry
08-30 14:17:54.573    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.574    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.574    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Android
08-30 14:17:54.575    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.576    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.577    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ IPhone
08-30 14:17:54.577    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.578    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.578    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ WindowsMobile
08-30 14:17:54.579    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:17:54.580    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:17:54.580    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Blackberry
08-30 14:50:56.032    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:50:56.034    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:50:56.034    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Android
08-30 14:50:56.035    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:50:56.042    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:50:56.042    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ IPhone
08-30 14:50:56.043    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:50:56.045    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:50:56.047    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ WindowsMobile
08-30 14:50:56.048    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms V/SaidursApp﹕ MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
08-30 14:50:56.051    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
08-30 14:50:56.052    4613-4613/me.saidur.bengalisms I/System.out﹕ Blackberry
```

Comment: Post the logcat output!

Comment: Logcat? we must see it..

Comment: @PareshMayani
log cat :
SmsMainPage class started
SmsMainPage  onCreate function started
SmsMainPageFragment function started
SmsMainPageFragment onCreateView function started
MobileArrayAdapter  function started
SmsMainPage  setOnItemClickListener started
MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started

Comment: Edit your message with full logcat.

Comment: @SaidurRahman No, this is not what we need. In the logcat you can see the exceptions. They are sort of easy to see

Comment: Android
MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
IPhone
MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
WindowsMobile
MobileArrayAdapter getView  function started
Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0c0051}
Blackberry
Displayed me.saidur.bengalisms/.SmsMainPage: +149ms (total +165ms)
App freeze timeout expired.
User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
Prepared write state in 9ms

Comment: You're casting View to TextView but it's not a TextView, it's whatever you're inflating, most likely some Layout.